# Inserting into STL Set of pair by sorting by second if first is same

Tags: c++, stl, set

I have a

```
pair<int, pair<int, string> >.
```

Now, I am inserting this into a STL Set of c++. It keeps the set sorted by the first value. But, if I insert a pair which has the same first value as some other, I want this to be sorted according to the second value according to larger first. I will give an example to make it clear.

```
#define pii pair<int, string>
#define pint pair< int , pii >
set< pint > S;
set< pint >::iterator it;
S.insert(make_pair(100, make_pair(1, "hi")));
S.insert(make_pair(50, make_pair(2, "hello")));
it = S.begin();
cout << it->second.second;
```

Here the output I get is

```
hello
```

But, now if I do,

```
S.insert(make_pair(50, make_pair(3, "dude")));
it = S.begin();
cout << it->second.second
```

Here also the output is

```
hello
```

But I want the output to be

```
dude
```

Because it's first value(50) is smaller than "hi"'s first value(100) and equal to "hello"'s first value(50). But, it's second value(3) is greater than "hi"'s second value(1) and also greater than "hello"'s second value.

Thank you.

Thus, if the first value is same then it must sort according to the second value but in larger second value first.

Comment: So just make your own `operator<` that compares them this way.

Comment: I changed it like this ideone.com/ya1nrg but it did not help. It returns "x" where I want it to be "y".

Comment: See Ruud v A's answer. You have to tell the `set` to use your comparison operator by wrapping it in a class. http://ideone.com/AQfmO1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see, the definition of `set` allows you to specify a comparison operation

```
template < class Key, class Compare = less<Key>,
       class Allocator = allocator<Key> > class set;
```

`Compare` can be a class which has an `operator()` that does the comparison. This operator takes two values, and needs to return `true` if the first is to be placed before the second in the set.

Comment: You have to wrap your comparison operator in a class and then tell the set to use it. See http://ideone.com/AQfmO1

Comment: Thank You! I also made it work but your code is so clean and reusable. http://ideone.com/ya1nrg Thank you again!